# Uninstall packages invisible in Android

Tags: android, package, uninstallation, root

I want to uninstall some useless apps from `/system`.
I have super access, and the permission `DELETE_PACKAGE` in the manifest.
But when I run

`Runtime.exec("pm uninstall package")`

I get

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10981): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10094 nor current process has android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES.
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Show us your AndroidManifest.xml please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't matter if you have root access or not. You will not be able to uninstall anything in /system without remounting it as read/write. /system is readonly.

you will have to run something like this:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

then do your `pm uninstall package`, and finally put the mount point back to readonly.

```
mount -o ro,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

chmod doesn't change the fact that everything in /system is readonly. that means NOTHING has permissions to modify or delete files. you have to remount it to remove it. just an FYI, you can edit your original question to add your manifest, but I don't need it, I know that is your issue.

if /system is readonly, you wont even be able to do `rm /system/somefile.ext`. you will get an error that /system is readonly. The same thing is probably happening when `pm uninstall` runs, and it just assumes its a permissions issue, which it sort of is.

Comment: this is my manifest
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".remove"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>

Comment: I think remount can't solve the security exception..
I tried chmod 777 /system/app/the_app which should have the same effect as remounting or?

Comment: With this Code I still get the Exception:
run.exec("su");
run.exec("mount -o remount,rw -t refs /dev/block/st19 /system");
run.exec("pm uninstall some.package");
When i type "mount" in adb shell it says it's mounted as rw.
I've tried a not system package and it also does not get uninstalled (same exception).
So any new ideas?
Sorry for late answer was in holiday.

Comment: i am not sure, but it sounds like android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES is a reserved permission for system applications. meaning only applications signed as a "system" application will have access to that permission. What happens if you run # pm uninstall some.package in adb?

Comment: Is this the right output that /system is mounted rw? :
/dev/block/st19 /system rfs rw,...
In adb shell pm uninstall system.package restults in a failure.
So then i will do this with rm the .apk, .odex and the /data/package directory.

Answer (score 0):

As I just read, /system on the galaxy s is rw at stock.
I agree with you that /system must be mounted before, but
as I am testing on a galaxy s this can't solve the error posted
above.
(mount is not even a valid command on the galaxy s).

Comment: I can assure you, /system is not rw, on the galaxy, or any device for that matter. a user could do a rm -f -r /system and wipe the entire device out. /system being rw is not going to happen. It might be rw @ initial boot, but the init script changes that. you could do a 'mount' from the terminal and it will output the mount points and if they are ro/rw.